# What's the absolute cheapest way to make a 4K HDMI recorder

Tags: sd, hdmi

I'm looking to build my own 4K HDMI recorder, because the products currently on the market are just to expensive for me.  As my title says, I'm trying to do that in the most low-cost way possible.

Thanks in advance

I doubt that my own idea about how to do this is accurate, but I'll mention it here anyway to show that I have attempted to do my own research:

I've noticed that HDMI has three TMDS data buses plus a clock bus.  It seems to me that these are the only ones that really carry high bandwidth, since the others are just handshakes and stuff.  It occurred to me that it might be possible to stream these directly into three separate sd cards just as the came from the hdmi input.  If three SD cards weren't enough, maybe I could split each TMDS line in two or three using some simple counter or flip/flop circuit for a total of six or nine sd cards.

EDIT: I appreciate all the constructive criticism.  My ignorance is revealed to me, and I've learned a lot about how things work and the proper way to calculate data rate.  I'll be wiser in the future.  I hope that this question will at least be useful for someone who comes after.

Comment: Probably getting someone in a q&a website to design you one...

Comment: HDMI is 10Gbps. SDcard is at best 100Mbps and on average closer to 10Mbps. You would need a minimum of 100 and maximum of 1000 SD cards to keep up.

Comment: I do love how the example you provided to show you did research just shows you know very little about what you're trying to do. If 4k hdmi recorders could be made by any non-professional in a basement they wouldn't cost so much...

Comment: Jury's out BUT just because HDMI 4K CAN do 16 GB/s that does not mean it's what all systems will need. The Sony A7S does 4k  4:2:2 30P 8 bit QFHD 3840 x 2160. Multiply that and you get 3840*2160*3*8*30=5.97 Gb/s.Hmmm sameish answer different path to WRB. BUT that's within spitting of "a few top end SSDs". Mayhaps 3 x SSD and some magic. Data rate of about 2 Gb/s/SSD or about 0.25 GB/s/SSD. So an hour would take about 3 x 1 TB SSDs. Starts to make the "only" $2000ish 3rd party recorder look about right :-). Std HDD are about say $40/TB so you can save your 4k video on disk for about $120/hour.

Comment: If you place any value on your time the cheapest way is to buy one. Work overtime, take a 2nd job, sell your body, it'll work out easier in the end.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to do a little research, plus some calculation, before you try this. Let us reason together.

4k video (2160p) is 8.29 Mpixel/frame, 120 frames/second, with each of three color channels sized at 12 bits/pixel. 3x12 bits is 36, so let's call the data requirement 5 bytes/pixel. Total data requirement is 8.29 x 120 x 5, or just on 5 GByte/sec. Note that, to a first approximation, this is one DVD's worth of data each second.

Now, SD cards. UHS I SD cards have a maximum transfer rate of 50 MByte/sec.

Aaaand the math says: you need 100 SD cards running simultaneously in order to keep up with the data flow.

If you go with UHS II cards, you'll cut the number of cards by about a factor of 3, to about 32 or so. Of course, UHS II cards have to be run on 0.4 volts, which may be a problem.

Not to mention the fact that, as someone with no high-speed digital experience, simply building the data busses to handle Gbit/second data rates will be, shall we say, an educational experience. Not fun, mind you, and probably not successful, but educational.

ETA: Another thing to think about is just how many SD cards you need to hold a movie. Let's figure 2 hours as a safe limit. That's 7200 seconds. Even if Russell McMahon is correct, and the data rate is 1 GByte/sec, that's 7.2 TByte total. The largest SD card that I know of is 512 GByte, so you would need about 14 separate cards to do the job. After all, it's not as if you can pause in the middle of a video and swap out cards. Well, you *can*, but only if you're playing off a recorder which you already have.

And if my 5 GByte/sec number is correct, you need about 70 cards.

Oh yes, and you might want to think about how you would store that many cards and not get the order mixed up.

Comment: That's "Educational" in the same sense as sticking you hand in an open fire is "educational".

Comment: "Those things which are painful, instruct." - Old Calvinist saying

Comment: See my comment on BonsaiOak's post. We are in approx agreement - but I think you MAY manage with say 3 x fastish SSDs.

Comment: No - I got the comparison wrong :-). When you and I got 5.x G... I was somewhat surprised and ran my and your figures again and got the same result. That was early am hours. Must have been more asleep than I realised. You get ~= 5 GB/s and I get Gb/s. A factor of ~= 8. Our assumptions differ. I THINK mine are correctish for the Sony 7s 4K video stream, but maybe not. Mine make sense for a $2000 recorder - which is available. Yours would be harder. There's 4K and there's 4K and some will be more 'accessible' than others. Even the 'slow' version is still somewhat hard to do.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - the big difference is that you're working with 30p, and I'm going with 120p.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Plus you are using 36 bits/pixel and I'm using 24. My specs came from the actual output of the Sony 7s rather than a generic spec. The 7S is not as capable as some others in some ways and much more capable in others. The very large sensor and low mp for the total sensor allows previously unheard of high ISO / low light level operation. You can hardly spot the camera when you see all the gear they bolt on around it. Failing 4k operation it does superb HD - at over 100,000 ISO .